# ResourceMapping in JSR286 SpringMVC portlets

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, liferay-6, jsr286

am developing a JSR286 portlet with springMVC. I have a div in my portlet which will iterate a collection in my model and showing it as below

```
<dl>
     <c:forEach var="product" items="${productList}">
        <dt>    
             <div><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/banner.jpg" /></div>
             <div>${product.name} - ${product.price}</div>
             <div>${product.serviceOne}</div>
             <div>${product.servicetwo}</div>
             <div>${product.serviceThree}</div>
        </dt>
     </c:forEach>
</dl>
```

I have previous and next link. on clicking the link i need to refresh the div with new content asynchronously(using ajax). Am using jQuery for scripting. i can replace the collection in the model using resource request(resource mapping url). but i dont know how to refresh the div in the ajax success so that the new collection can be viewed in the portlet.

Techies give your suggesstions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a New jsp with the iterating logic alone. In the resource request i have returned the jsp name, thereby view resolver picked the corresponding jsp from the view folder and returned the executed  contents as the response. i have placed the contents  to the div in tha ajax success.
below is the code

```
@ResourceMapping("filterProducts")
public String filterProducts(Model model, ResourceRequest request,
          ResourceResponse response,
          @ModelAttribute("productModel") ProductModel productModel,
          ModelMap modelMap) throws IOException {
                   model.addAttribute("productModel", updatedProductModel);
                   return "productDetails";
}

$.ajax({
    url : fltURL,
    type : 'POST',
    datatype : 'html',  
    success : function(_html) {                         
          $('#midcontainer').html(_html);
    },
    error : function() {
          alert('error');
    }});

<portlet:resourceURL var="filterProductsURL" id="filterProducts"></portlet:resourceURL>
```